# Edit plist of an Xcode project from terminal

Tags: swift, xcode, terminal

I want find and edit plist of my Xcode project. the property that I want edit is `Supports opening documents in place` and I want give a Yes value. The issue is here when I open my Xcode project in Finder, I cannot find the plist, there for I cannot locate it in first place to start edit. Let say I have an iOS Xcode project called Test on the Desktop, where is the plist? Also I am going edit the plist with Terminal commands.

Comment: It's inside the .xcode "package", you can right-click (or Cmd+click) and select **Show Package Contents** then look in **project.pbxproj**, I would advise against of editing it directly though.

Comment: I want edit plist just for special project of Xcode saved on Desktop, not Xcode plist or setting or other thing.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find the related `pbxproj` located inside xcodeproj directory (package contents) and edit it as text file, find the `INFOPLIST_KEY'`s entries and add `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` key as follow:

```
INFOPLIST_KEY_LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace = YES;
```

Comment: It looks like a json file for me the values inside pbxproj, if wanted edit a plist of an Xcode project with another Xcode program, I should decode it, right, but I want use Terminal for this with command how can I do it with code without editing manually as you said?