# Editing an Xcode project via Terminal command

Tags: swift, xcode, bash, terminal

I can open one of my Xcode project in Xcode and add `Application supports iTunes file sharing=Yes` to plist with Xcode and through Xcode directly, Now I was wandering if this work code be done completely via Terminal as well?

**My Goal** is type a command in Terminal that does the same work for plist just with Terminal and without opening Xcode program and doing it manually just with Terminal command. For example I have a random Xcode project saved on my Desktop, and since Xcode is accessible via Terminal, I want make this work.

Comment: Info.plist is just a text file containing XML. You can use any of the command line text editors to edit it. Just add `<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key><true/>` inside the `<dict>` tag. Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: How is this different from your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70828844/edit-plist-of-an-xcode-project-from-terminal) question?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: If I do not receive the correct answer, maybe I asked in bad way, I tried to give more detail to my issue. Basically they are same in logic.

Comment: @Sweeper: I do not know, tell my if I was clear, I have an Xcode project created and saved on my Desktop or any other location that we know the path of it. Now I am closing Xcode program, then opening Terminal, what I should type in Terminal to make my goal in question possible?

Comment: What's the content of you Info.plist? Is it in binary format?

Comment: @Fravadona: I am able to see and edit my plist in Xcode program using Xcode 13.0+, but after quitting Xcode, I see no plist in Finder when I am looking to my saved project.

Comment: searching for the plist file `find projectdir -iname '*.plist'`

Comment: what is that? @Fravadona

Comment: That's how to find the plist file from the terminal; you won't be able to do anything if you don't know where the file is

Comment: @Fravadona: Ok, as we know in Xcode 13.0+ we got NO plist, let say my Xcode project called `Test`, and it located on my Desktop, how could be able use your comment?

Comment: `find ~/Desktop -iname '*.plist'` will list all the `.plist` files in your desktop

Comment: @Fravadona: Nice I could reach for 2 .plist, `xcschememanagement.plist` 
 and `IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist`, any idea for next steps?

Answer (score 0):

As @Sweeper already answered you should got to the path of your .plist file and then write the following command:

```
vim Info.plist
```

This will open an editor which then you need to click on "i", then input the following line into the main  tag:

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key><true/>
```

Then click "esc" then ":" then "w" then "q" and finally "Enter" and you are done.

Comment: No, I am not able to see my .plist in my Xcode project firstly using Xcode 13.0+, secondly as I said I am looking to type a command in Terminal, not using an editor like vim for that reason. I hope I could make it more clear, I am looking for command not editor!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: See after all explaining some come with such answer.  I explicitly said looking for Command in Terminal.